# Can two Isosceles Triangles form a Square/Rectangle

Tags: geometry

Just out of curiosity, I tried to find if it was possible to make a square/rectangle out of two isosceles triangles. Is it really impossible to do so? Moreover, can a square/rectangle be cut into two isosceles triangles.

Though after trying to draw some pictures it seems impossible, is there a formal proof for it?

Clearly, a right triangle with a $45^\circ$ angle is an exception, but for the rest?

This question is not from any textbook, so I don't know if it holds any importance.

Comment: Take a square and one diagonal. You have two isosceles trinagles.

Comment: Is this statement enough to formally rule out the possibility that no other isosceles triangles can be formed other than the $45^0$ right triangles?

Comment: @mathx, Without 45-90-45 triangles, you will be able to construct only a rhombus or a parallelogram, which will be a square/rectangle respectively iff the isosceles triangles are 45-90-45 triangles.

Comment: To get a rectangle from your two isosceles triangles you want two of the six angles to be $90^\circ$ and two pairs of the other angles to add up to $90^\circ$.  That is rather constraining for isosceles triangles

Comment: @Henry Exactly. Only a rhombus is possible. Your statement seems enough to prove the statement that no such division is possible. Thanks.

Comment: @mathx some kites and some non-rectangular parallelograms are possible, as well as any rhombus or square